# Ensuring an Item Is Selected

Tags: java, event-handling

I'm doing practices of a Java book and I came up to an event handling code like below. My question is if itemStateChanged method called when an item is selected from a JComboBox then why we should ensure that an item is selected?

```
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
{
      if(event.getStateChange()
           == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
           label.setIcon(icons[
           imagesJComboBox.getSelectedIndex()]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to check if the method supposed to be called on a particular event really matches the correct event.

Since the method is `public`, it can be used within any other situation or event. The call of the method itself doesn't secure the event maches `ItemEvent.SELECTED` itself.